# Java hashmap max size of 5770?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was testing some file/profile transferring things today. I used a `HashMap` to store a players name and the value of there profile. However I noticed my hashmap only goes up to 5770 in  size. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String s : dataFile.getConfigurationSection("users").getKeys(false)) {
        temp.put(s, dataFile.getString("users." + s + ".group"));
}
```

That's what i'm using to grab the player and their "group".

Comment: How can you say "my hashmap only goes up to 5770 in size" ? How did you check that ?

Comment: @ortis Oh sorry, I have a System.out.println(temp.size());

Comment: This is not the max size, this is the current size of the `HashMap`. `HashMap` size are only limited by the heap size of the JVM and `Integer.MaxValue`.

Comment: @ortis well I figured this, but my issue is that I have 11,000 profiles to transfer and it only loads 5770.

Comment: "dataFile.getConfigurationSection("users").getKeys(false)" seems to be your problem.

Comment: Is it possible that the variable `s` is not unique ? Because if a key already exist in the `HashMap`, it will be overided by the new one when calling `temp.put`

Comment: what does "getKeys(false)"mean in this context?

Comment: @ortis yes there minecraft UUID's

Comment: @Ben getKeys(false); tells whether or not you want to return the keys of the path variable to get there, e.g. "Users.<everything>"

Comment: You got your response then. `HashMap` can only contain UNIQUE key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HashMap is not limited, your problem is probably you have repeating keys..

I would check if the key is contained already before putting it in the map:

```
if(temp.containsKey(s)){
 System.out.println("Erasing key "+s+" val "+temp.get(s));
}
temp.put(s, dataFile.getString("users." + s + ".group"));
```

Answer (score 17):

**HashMap is not limited**, provided to have a load factor is increased.

In Sun's JVM, `HashMap` uses an array which is a power of 2. The largest power of two allowed for an array size is `2^30`. And the largest number of elements you can have before the HashMap will try to double its size to 2^31 (which it cannot do) is (`2^30 * loadFactor`) or about 700 million for the default load factor.

Comment: The arrays are indexed by integers and that is the "limitation" on  maximum size of the array. The power of 2 is the pattern the array increases